# how to get id from between several image-buttons and write with ajax get in console.log?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel

> I can not pass the id of my buttons in ajax, it appears **MY_id**
> **undefined** as output from console.log can someone help me ?
>
> my problem is when I choose my imagebutton and then I click on my send button. the value of the id of the imagebutton is not captured, how do I solve it?

```
<html>
    <input type="image" id="name-1" src="img.png"  onclick="reply_click(this.id)" class="btTxt submit "  width="100" height="130" /> 
    <input type="image" id="name-2" src="img.png" onclick="reply_click(this.id)" class="btTxt submit"  width="100" height="130" /> 
    <input type="image" id="name-3" src="img.png" onclick="reply_click(this.id)" class="btTxt submit" width="100" height="130" /> 
    <input type="image" id="name-N" src="img.png" onclick="reply_click(this.id)" class="btTxt submit" width="100" height="130" /> 
    <button type="MYbutton" id="openButton" class="btn btn-primary">MYtext</button>
        <script>
            function reply_click(clicked_id ){
                $(function() {
                    $('#openButton').on('click', function() {
                          var x = document.getElementById(clicked_id).innerHTML;
                        $.get('MYURL.com',function(data){
                            console.log('MY_id'+ x);
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
        </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: `this` in callbacks is not same as outside the callback see [How to access correct `this` in callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: get the id value and write in the console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved my problem.

```
      <script>
            function reply_click(clicked_id){
                $(function() {
                    $('#openButton').on('click', function() {
                        $.get('MY_URL',function(data){
                            console.log('MY_id:  '+ clicked_id);
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
</script>
```